# How to design a Bulk GET call?

Tags: java, rest

What is the best way to design an API that facilitates a request for a bulk GET? I have a use case where I want to return multiple entities to a service and I would not want to make a single GET call each resource.

Comment: You can expose new endpoint which take list of parameter to find and return all in one go

Comment: The query params for entity filtering by appropriate criteria should work.

Comment: Keep in mind, there is a URL size limit of ~2000 characters. In some cases, it's more appropriate to use a POST for bulk requests, depending on the size of the values in the request (e.g. primary IDs). A possible alternative, depending on how you're retrieving your data, is to use some sort of range, e.g. `idsFrom=0&idsTo=100`

Comment: @Noshaf that seems like a good way here

Comment: but as @Christopher pointed out, the URL size limit is a concern which is true in our case as well. And searching across a range is really neat trick too! but it unfortunately won't work in this case as I am fetching on reference Ids.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common task with HTTP APIs. As such there's two prevalent solutions.

Arguably the most common is to use a `POST` request. In the body of the `POST` request you should specify both the *type* of request you are making and *what* you are requesting. You should give a type in the request since `POST` is just a general request that the server performs whatever action is given in the payload.

For example:

```
POST /resources
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "action": "get",
  "ids": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

The other option is a `GET` request with a body. The request would likely look similar to that of the `POST` request above but without the requirement of specifying the action. You can see this approach used in projects such as [ElasticSearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch). The HTTP specification is vague on its definition when it comes to `GET` requests having a body (see [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1)).

Specifically the RFC says:

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

Whilst I can't speak for the developers of ElasticSearch I expect the last part of the quote ("some existing implementations [may] reject the request") was one of the reasons that ElasticSearch **accepts both `GET` and `POST` requests for bulk requests**.

Answer (score 0):

Having one resource that returns a representation of multiple entities is *fine*.  Think search results in google, questions in stack overflow, past orders in Amazon.

You do need to be aware of the implications on cache invalidation.  See [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234).  The basic issue being that, as far as general purpose components are concerned, different resources are unrelated -- invalidating one doesn't change the others (expect in limited circumstances).  With "the same" information cached under two different API keys, inconsistencies may result.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is becoming a common use case under Data-as-a-service where either there are bulk requests for GET operations or for POST (CUD) operations. The choice of architecture will determined by multiple factors.

I am answering only on basis of ***Data Volume*** factor:
For lesser volume, single node/server can complete a given request but what if you are trying to 'query' or 'update' thousands or millions of records. Such cases might need distribution of work-load to multiple worker nodes and hence an Async, Event-driven, Containerized, Messaging kind of setup might be more suitable

**Example:**
You may send a single request to server - which in-turn can distribute the workload to multiple workers, and each worker then posts the response to a queue from where the original client can come and pick results after some time.